# Choice of JVM hosting solution for ActiveMQ processing application

Tags: java, hosting, activemq-classic

I need some advice regarding potential hosting solutions - there is an incredible amount of choice and confusing options out there.

Basically I have a Java application that contains an embedded ActiveMQ message broker. The job  of this application is to:

1) Process Messages (JMS) recieved on the broker from 10-15 sources
2) Publish Messages (JMS) to a different JMS broker on another server (in our office).

So, I am looking for something that will not cost the earth (this is only for testing purposes) but could offer decent RAM and processing speed options so that we can really test the limits of the application (we need to see what the bottleneck is, whether it is Active MQ or the processing APP).

Also, the outgoing bandwidth costs will need to be a consideration. Again, the volumes will be sporadic and sometimes signficant (depending on the intensity of testing periods).

Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is the right forum for this sort of question.

Comment: Right. Perhaps an explanation as to why? I would hate to do it again.

Comment: Explaination:  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com) is what you are searching for. There is a [monthly free tier](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/billing) and you can [run any Java application](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/java). There is no ActiveMQ available, but [via add-ons](https://addons.heroku.com/cloudamqp) you can use RabbitMQ, which also supports the JMS. You can increase performance of you application at any time - have a look at Herokus [pricing](https://www.heroku.com/pricing#0-0).